# Resources on twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hey I am new to web development and I want to get started with twitter bootstrap. I searched the internet for some good resources on developing with bootstrap but I couldn't find. I am unable to find complete tutorial series on bootstrap. I need guidance and some good tutorials as well to develop using bootstrap specifically with ASP.net.

Comment: What's wrong with the documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/? That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lynda.com also has a good tutorial on Bootstrap, the course is easy and you should follow along with the exercise files... Bootstrap 2 and Bootstrap 3 are both available :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well if documentation on [bootstrap site](http://www.getbootstrap.com) isn't clear enough for you, then you should go a step back and get yourself familiar with css and basic jQuery.

You can head over to http://net.tutsplus.com and find some tutorials that are up to your speed.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of tutorials that will get your feet wet:

**Exploring the Bootstrap 3.0 Grid System**
http://fearlessflyer.com/exploring-the-bootstrap-3-0-grid-system/

then I wrote **Create a Responsive Photo Gallery with Bootstrap Framework**
http://fearlessflyer.com/create-a-responsive-photo-gallery-with-bootstrap-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Another option that you may find useful when learning the ropes of Bootstrap is taking a look at different Bootstrap Templates and Themes. [PrepBootstrap](http://bootsnipp.com/) and [BootSnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/) are two sites dedicated to such resources and may be a very good start.